# Overwriting flag set in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS by flag set in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG

Tags: c++, cmake

On my system, CMake populates `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with `O2` optimization flags and
and I add `O0` flags for the debug configurations, such that I find this in my CMakeCache.txt:

```
//Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-O2

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-O0
```

According to the documentation of CMake, the configuration dependent flags are appended. The issue with this seems to be, that the `02` flag appears to take precedence over the `O0` flag. Is there a way to configure CMake, possibly from cli call to it, such that it uses `O0` instead?

Comment: "The issue with this seems to be, that the 02 flag appears to take precedence over the O0 flag." - Have you checked the **exact command line** CMake generates for the compiler? This should be the first step when debug issues with option's overwriting. If you use `make` as a build tool, then you could run `make VERBOSE=1` for show exact commands which are executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very confusing so I set up a very small test.

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
project(test)
add_executable( test test.cpp )

$ cat test.cpp
int main() {
}
```

Then I build with default options and look at the resulting options. Check that the resulting flags are empty. In the command line, cmake adds "-MT -MD" for dependency checking.

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
$ grep ^CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMakeCache.txt
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

Now compiling for release mode. Check that the options in the cache are exactly the same but cmake is now using the release options.

```
$ rm -rf * 
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
$ grep ^CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMakeCache.txt 
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

Now let's change the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable directly. The option has been prepended to the make command line but in the cache file everything else remains the same.

```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O1" ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O1 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
$ grep ^CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMakeCache.txt 
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-O1
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

Let's now change the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` variable directly to see what happens. Looks like now we were able to replace the optimization flags with our own.

```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O1" ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O1 -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
$ grep ^CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMakeCache.txt 
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O1
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

cmake also provides a `CMAKE_<LANGUAGE>_FLAGS_<BUILDMODE>_INIT` option. Let's see what is the impact.

```
$ rm -rf * 
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT="-O1" ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O1 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
$ grep ^CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMakeCache.txt 
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O1 -O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT:UNINITIALIZED=-O1
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
```

So the effect of those `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<MODE>_INIT` variables is the same as setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, it prepends them to the command line, but you can configure individually for each mode - release, debug, relwithdebinfo.

So to the point of your question, setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` directly should override the other default options *if you compile in debug mode*.

Comment: I got it a typo

Comment: But don't the lines 
```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O1" ..
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O1 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT ... -c /tmp/test/test.cpp
```

display the issue? Building release has two optimization flags: `/usr/bin/c++ -O1 -O3` and on my system it uses the first (i.e. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`) and not the configuration dependent (`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`). I notice this, since my debug builds have many optimized away positions.

Comment: @MKuhne Yes, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT is not your solution. You should overwrite CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG directly and it should have solved your problem.

Comment: Maybe  I get this one wrong. Changing `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-O0` does not solve the problem, since the cached `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2` is applied (first). Also in your example `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O1"` you find that both optimization flags for all builds and release builds are applied `/usr/bin/c++ -O1 -O3` and, at least on my system, the first flag is used. Thus here, although you build for release, you will get a build with `O1` optimization instead of `O3`.